# TYPO3 symfony console command: where to put/get configuration settings?

Tags: symfony, typo3, typo3-10.x, typo3-console

I wrote a symfony console command for downloading CSV files from a remote server and importing data from those files into some database tables of my extension. This works fine so far (run from CLI or scheduler).

But to do all this, I need a bunch of configuration settings (credentials for the remote server, list of files to download, storagePid etc.) and I don't know where to put them. For the time being, it's all hardcoded, which is obviously bad. Of course I can just invent my own config file, put it somewhere sensible and include it in my code. But that seems messy and arbitrary.

Is there a recommended/best practice way to store such configuration settings? Ideally, I want them to be in my site package. For FE plugins we have Typoscript settings + constants and we can use similar mechanisms for BE modules. But what's the best strategy for this kind of CLI context?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can used Extension configuration (ext_conf_template.txt), you can set all the configuration there and it can be accessed through the scheduler as well as CLI I guess, using this API :

```
$extensionConfiguration = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ExtensionConfiguration::class)->get('my_extension_key');
```

You can find more information here : [Extension configuration](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationOptions/Index.html)

And in your command class, you can use the function Command::configure() in order to initialize the command configuration.

See : [Symfony Console Command](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/CommandControllers/Index.html)

Comment: I thought about that as well and it's certainly much better than the hardcoded approach. But I don't think the extension configuration is well suited for inclusion in a site package.

Comment: IMHO I think it's a good place to put the configuration in the extension included the CLI command and if it's the site package extension why don't you think it's not well suited ?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point. Do you suggest that I put the configuration of my importer extension into the extension configuration of the site package and load it from there? But then I have another hardcoded dependency, because the name of the site package is site/project specific and might be different in another project.

Comment: No, what I suggest you is to put the configuration in the Typo3 extension where your CLI command is implemented and then on each site you install this extension, you can configure through the extension configuration the settings (credentials for the remote server, list of files to download, storagePid etc.).

Comment: So the the configuration settings are NOT in the site package... My understanding of a site package is that all site-specific settings + configurations should go into the site package. That's why I think the extension configuration is not ideal if you work with site packages.

Comment: No your wrong, not all the configuration settings should go in site package, you should find global configuration here but if you have a specific extension you can - and usually must - set the specific configuration for this extension in its configuration settings in order to have this extension independent from site package. So ext_conf_template.txt let you define default configuration that can be changed through BE > Admin Tools > Settings > Configure Extension > You extension

Comment: Did you try this solution, does it solves your problem ?

Comment: No I didn't try, because I'm familiar with extension configuration settings and how to implement it. And no it doesn't solve my problem, because it's not under version control. According to the official TYPO3 site package tutorial, version control is one of the main benefits of a site package.